# Save JavaDStream<List<String>> as parquet in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have the below code,

```
JavaDStream<List<String>> records = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, List<String>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        List<String> splitJsons = new ArrayList<String>();
        @Override
        public List<String> call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
            splitJsons = buildResultMap(tuple2._2());
            return splitJsons;
        }

    });
```

Now, I need to save "records" as parquet using Java Dataframe API.
I tried as below,

```
records.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction2<JavaRDD<List<String>>, Time>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<List<String>> rddList, Time time) throws Exception {
            sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rddList.context());
            DataFrame wordsDataFrame = rddList.flatMap(w => Record(w)).toDF();
            wordsDataFrame.write().mode("Append").parquet("/tmp/parquet");

        }

    });
```

But, I am unable to convert `JavaDStream<List<String>` to Dataframe. It seems I have to convert `JavaDStream<List<String>>` to `JavaDStream<String>` and then convert it into Dataframe.

Comment: Parquet is a column-oriented format. It doesnt't make much sense to store lists. You may want to define a record type instead. If your requirement is to store arbitrary lists, then you should consider another file format.

Comment: Any code sample @maasg ???

Comment: I'm saying that you need to re-think your approach. I don't think there's a code sample for that.